# Common gradle config in project-level or global build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project that has multiple modules in it, and each of those modules has a signingConfig that is the same to all modules. I want to move that singingConfig to the global gradle which is located at the root of the project to get rid of the redundancy of that config.

Same problem with the androidTestCompile, I get an error if I moved it to the global build.gradle. Does anyone have experience on how to move it to the global gradle?

btw, there are reasons why I always signed my app in every module, one is for the unit and instrumentation test, since testing will only cover that particular module and others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the "apply" command in Gradle tool, like below :

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/config/common.gradle"
```

In the common.gradle file, you may write the common setting, like

```
android{

    Properties configs = new Properties()
    ....

    defaultConfig {
       ... 
    }

    buildTypes {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
          ...
    }
}
```

then you may have a concise build.gradle.

The file structure looks like below :

```
rootDir
 |
 |-- config
 |      | -- common.gradle
 |      | -- util.gradle
 |
 |-- moduleA
 |      | -- build.gradle
 |      | -- src
 |
 |-- moduleB
 |      | -- build.gradle
 |      | -- src
 ...
 |
 |-- settings.gradle
 |-- build.gradle
```

Comment: Thanks @Zephyr. I tried the 
apply from: "${rootDir}/common.gradle"
on my modules' gradle. 
and throw an error that could not read script
but it works on both
apply from: '' + rootDir + '/common.gradle' and apply from: '../common.gradle'

Comment: my bad. it just need double quote not single quote. It's fixed. Thanks @Zephyr

Comment: The rootDir is a Gradle property so ${rootDir} should be fine in a .gradle file,     I guess the issue is in the file structure.